# How robust is this simple code for checking facsimile files? Java

Tags: java, duplicates

I've managed to put-together this very simple programme to check two files for facsimile. It seems to work with JPEGs, PDFs, MOVs and MP3s, and so I assume all other popular image, video and audio file-types.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class java_canvas {
    
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
    
    Path file_path_1 = Paths.get("/*first file-path*/");
    Path file_path_2 = Paths.get("/*second file-path*/");
    
    byte[] file_1_bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file_path_1);
    byte[] file_2_bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file_path_2);
    
    if(Arrays.equals(file_1_bytes, file_2_bytes) == true){
        
        System.out.println("they're duplicates");
    
    }
    
}}
```

Before writing this programme I asked elsewhere about how I could write it, see this [Imgur picture](https://imgur.com/a/BIt9HWQ) for an image of what I was advised.

Why was what I was advised so enormously more complicated than the code I have written? Have a missed some crucial steps in my code? I mean it seems to work fine upon testing it: duplicates do indeed get checked as facsimile and files which are even slightly different to one-another don't pass. I stated to these other people I asked help from that I was a beginner, yet they've suggested to me things that I can't understand a word of. Why didn't they advise me something similar to what I've coded here instead?

Checked all the automated duplicate-question-suggestions. Don't see how I could possibly re-phrase this question to be any "better". Don't see what research I could do further into this besides simply studying Java more or paying a mentor to help me with it.

Comment: Would you not want to run a sha1sum instead and compare that? I would imagine comparing the total size of bytes has various collisions you would hit between different files but same size.

Comment: If two files are very similar images, this will not match.  This will also use a lot of memory for most files.